# Translate MATLAB expressions containing "^" power operator to C++ syntax

Tags: c++, matlab

Brief:
I have several very large math expressions written in Matlab/Octave syntax. I 
want to evaluate them within a C++ function by copy and pasting them in, however the problem is they contain "^" operators that cannot be overloaded to work with doubles.

Details:
The expressions consist of scalar variables with nested trigonometric functions, addition and multiplication operators and power operators "^". There are so many expressions that it is not practical to manually edit them to be C++ compatible. The main problem arises with the power operator "^" which is reserved in C++ for the bitwise exclusive OR operation. I am developing this code to run on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with gcc version 4.9.2.

I am asking for advice on how to proceed/comments on the following three ideas:

1) Write a new class that consists of "double-like" variables and an overloaded "^" operator, as well as "+,*,-" operators and trig functions.

2) Write some code to parse the MATLAB expressions, find each "^" character, identify the base term "a" and the exponent term "b" and replace them with the pow(a,b)

3) Look for some package online that has already done #1.

Backstory: 
I am porting a large optimization code that originally used Mathematica to evaluate gradients, jacobians, etc. These Mathematica expressions were converted to Matlab using the ToMatlab[] package:
http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/
I now have a need to re-write the whole thing in C++.

There are hundreds of expressions similar to:

```
 grad_out(1,1) = k1^(-1)*k2^(-1)*(k1*k2*(r+(-1)*R)*cos(b1*k1)+(-1)* 
        k1^2*R*cos((b1+g1)*k1)+k1*k2*R*cos((b1+g1)*k1)+(-1)* 
        k1^2*r*cos((b1+g1)*k1+g1*k2)+k1^2*R*cos((b1+g1)*k1+g1* 
        k2)+k1^2*r*cos((b1+g1)*k1+(b2+g1)*k2)+(-1)*k1^2*k2*L* 
        sin((b1+g1)*k1));
```

Comment: You can't just expect the syntax of one language to also be valid in an unrelated language. Manual translation would probably give the best results, also considering that there might be other subtle semantic differences between languages. If you happen to know how to write parsers, you could do #2 within three hours, but piling automatic translation on top of automatic translation just results in the kind of utterly unmaintainable code you currently have before you – when you go the manual route, use the opportunity to factor out all common subexpressions!

Comment: Amon, thanks for taking a look at this. Note that the above expression cannot be simplified. In my opinion, manual translation would be error prone so I am avoiding it. I don't see what's "unmaintainable" about the above code?

Comment: you can't overload ^ because the precedence rules are not right for it, so your expressions would not come out the way you expect. Probably your best bet is sed or some other powerful replacer calling a pow() function.

Comment: @arwo "Note that the above expression cannot be simplified." `(r+(-1)*R)`. Yes, it can - maybe not a huge simplification, but it can be simplified a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab's symbolic toolbox can generate C code from a matlab expression using [ccode](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ccode.html):

```
syms b1 b2 g1 g2 k1 k2 L r R x1
ccode(k1^(-1)*k2^(-1)*(k1*k2*(r+(-1)*R)*cos(b1*k1)+(-1)*k1^2*R*cos((b1+g1)*k1)+k1*k2*R*cos((b1+g1)*k1)+(-1)*k1^2*r*cos((b1+g1)*k1+g1*k2)+k1^2*R*cos((b1+g1)*k1+g1*k2)+k1^2*r*cos((b1+g1)*k1+(b2+g1)*k2)+(-1)*k1^2*k2*L*sin((b1+g1)*k1)))
```

Outputs

```
t0 = -(-(k1*k1)*r*cos(k1*(b1+g1)+k2*(b2+g1))-R*(k1*k1)*cos(g1*k2+k1*(b1+g1))+(k1*k1)*r*cos(g1*k2+k1*(b1+g1))+R*(k1*k1)*cos(k1*(b1+g1))+L*(k1*k1)*k2*sin(k1*(b1+g1))+k1*k2*cos(b1*k1)*(R-r)-R*k1*k2*cos(k1*(b1+g1)))/(k1*k2);
```

Comment: Thanks, toasted_flakes. This is what I was looking for. I also came across a neat package that converts MATLAB syntax to C++ code compatible with the armadillo linear algebra library: https://github.com/jonathf/matlab2cpp

Answer (score -1):

C# has pretty powerful regular expressions, you could make a command line program or something else...

This in C# uses Balanced Grouping Expressions to match parens:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main ( string [] args )
        {
            const string identifier = @"[a-zA-Z0-9_]+";

            string expression = @"grad_out(1,1) = (k1*(2+(3))*k2)^(-1)+k3^(k2+1)+(k4)^(-1)+k5^(k6^k7);";

            System.Console.WriteLine ( expression );
            System.Console.WriteLine ( "\r\n=\r\n" );

            var regExString = @"(?<left>(" + identifier + @")|(((?<L0>\()[^()]*)+([^()]*(?<-L0>\)))+))" + @"\^" + @"(?<right>(" + identifier + @")|(((?<L1>\()[^()]*)+([^()]*(?<-L1>\)))+))";
            var re = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex ( regExString );

            bool changed;
            do
            {
                var nextExpression = re.Replace ( expression, @"pow(${left},${right})" );
                changed = nextExpression != expression;
                expression = nextExpression;
            } while ( changed );

            System.Console.WriteLine ( expression );
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
grad_out(1,1) = pow((k1*(2+(3))*k2),(-1))+pow(k3,(k2+1))+pow((k4),(-1))+pow(k5,(pow(k6,k7)));
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/7898310/471129,
and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx